# Wso2 ESB fault receiving and fault sending in JMX attributes

Tags: jmx, wso2, wso2-identity-server, wso2-esb

Hi am working on Wso2ESB 4.9.0 and recently while monitoring JMX attributes of the ESB server and observed there are some fault receiving and fault sending and timeouts are happening in the ESB.

Below are the the attributes of the following objects in JMX:

org.apache.synapse:Type=Transport,Name=passthru-http-sender
org.apache.synapse:Type=Transport,Name=passthru-http-receiver

```
 [EsbMonitoring] ***************** Transport http Attributes *********************
 [EsbMonitoring] Sender Stats---------------------
 [EsbMonitoring] Active threads           :0
 [EsbMonitoring] FaultsReceiving          :3
 [EsbMonitoring] FaultsSending            :3
 [EsbMonitoring] TimeoutsReceiving        :34
 [EsbMonitoring] TimeoutsSending          :0
 [EsbMonitoring] QueueSize                :0
 [EsbMonitoring] MessagesSent             :28786806
 [EsbMonitoring] MessagesReceived         :28786728
 [EsbMonitoring] Receiver Stats-------------------
 [EsbMonitoring] Active threads           :0
 [EsbMonitoring] FaultsReceiving          :69
 [EsbMonitoring] FaultsSending            :0
 [EsbMonitoring] TimeoutsReceiving        :0
 [EsbMonitoring] TimeoutsSending          :0
 [EsbMonitoring] QueueSize                :0
 [EsbMonitoring] MessagesSent             :12210777
 [EsbMonitoring] MessagesReceived         :12228538
```

They are some fault receiving and fault sending connections between Wso2ESB and Wso2DSS,There are around 34 timeouts receiving and 3 each on fault sending and receiving in the passthru-http-sender and 69 fault receiving on passthru-http-reveived side,what is the exact reason this faults happen. How to know the reason why this happened and how to avoid such things.

Comment: Add logging to fault sequence and see what is wrong.

Comment: Hi @simar i have logs in my fault sequence but no use there all the database related errors get logged but no specific logs for the above problem.

Comment: Timeout receiveing - connection is established, but sender server was during shutdown so no data sent till timeout is happen. FaultsSending             - unable to establish connection (sometimes happen)

Comment: You can enable logging on http level (configure log4j file), but ti will consume huge amount of space for logs.